# How to implement Parallelism in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-10, postgresql-11

I am working on a functionality for updating batch logs based on tenant key and other query condition.

In my functionality I use a join and loop through the records one by one, updating the batch log in sequence.

My code is below

```
CREATE TABLE linen_tenant_header
(
    tenant_key character varying(200) NOT NULL,
    tenant_name character varying(50) NOT NULL,
    email character varying(50) NOT NULL,
    created_user character varying(200) NOT NULL,
    updated_user character varying(200),
    created_time timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now(),
    updated_time timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now()
);

CREATE TABLE linen_sc_batch_log
    (
    batch_id serial NOT NULL,
    profile_header_id integer NOT NULL,
    batch_status character varying(200),
    batch_type character varying(200) NOT NULL,
    batch_mode character varying(200) NOT NULL,
    tenant_key character varying(200) NOT NULL,
    created_user character varying(200),
    updated_user character varying(200),
    created_time timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now(),
    updated_time timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now(),
);

CREATE TABLE linen_sc_expressions
(
    expression_id integer NOT NULL,
    reference_id integer NOT NULL,
    tenant_key character varying(200) NOT NULL,
    expression_text character varying(10000) NOT NULL,
    start_date date NOT NULL,
    end_date date,
    created_user character varying(200) NOT NULL,
    updated_user character varying(200),
    created_time timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now(),
    updated_time timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now()
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sample_function(
    tenant_key TEXT
) RETURNS VOID AS $$
DECLARE
    rec RECORD;
BEGIN
    FOR rec IN SELECT * FROM linen_sc_batch_log bl, linen_sc_expressions sce  where bl.profile_header_id = sce.reference_id and bl.tenant_key = $1 and sce.tenant_key = $1
    LOOP
        EXECUTE FORMAT('UPDATE linen_sc_batch_log set batch_status = %L where tenant_key = %L and batch_id = %L::INTEGER', 'EXTRACTED', tenant_key, rec.batch_id);
    END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

My functionality works correctly, but I need to enhance my functionality by adding parallelism.

Instead of looping through all the records, I want to update all the records at the same time in parallel.

I have researched on google and PostgreSQL articles but didn't find a related concept.

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be done in a single SQL statement:

```
UPDATE linen_sc_batch_log AS bl
SET batch_status = 'EXTRACTED'
FROM linen_sc_expressions AS sce
WHERE bl.profile_header_id = sce.reference_id
  AND bl.tenant_key = $1 AND sce.tenant_key = $1;
```

If you want that parallelized, you can run several such updates on concurrent database connection, adding a clause like `AND id % 10 = n` to each.

Comment: yaa we can do but in case of nested loop and complex functionality or for millions of records it is taking very very much time so we need parallelism. so for sample functionality i have posted question. Please this question needed parallelism implementation

Comment: I have added something.